# Pairwise t test (holm correction) with ezANOVA output

Tags: r, posthoc

I'd like to perform post-hoc comparisons using the pairwise.t.test function in R and the output of the ANOVA I performed with ezANOVA but I don't know how.
I'd like to perform post-hoc comparisons for the group factor (3 levels).

Here is the code for the ANOVA

```
anova_age = ezANOVA(data = data_age_anova,
                       dv = age_years,
                       wid = participant_id,
                       between = group,
                       type = 3,
                       return_aov = T)
```

How shall I use the pairwise.t.test function after that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can check out this prior post. And if you are still stuck afterward, consider posting in the statistics stack, where the central focus are the tests, but most people have skills in R, Python and Matlab sufficient to get you where you need to go!

Comment: @sconfluentus thank you but to which post are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the link, but @IRTFM has it!